# Google Firestore - What is OR equivalent?

Tags: nosql, google-cloud-firestore

I see having mulitple `where` acts like `AND`, but how about `OR`?

Answer (score 1):

You can't really do an OR query in Cloud Firestore.

As a workaround, you could run two separate queries and merge them together on the client, or add some custom field that would essentially perform the "OR" query for you on the database. (For an example of that latter one, if you know you're going to often run an "age > 65 OR age < 18" query on the database, you could create a specific `age_high_or_low` field that you would set to true if the age field were greater than 65 or less then 18.)

Comment: Do you happen to know the reason behind the decision to not support `OR`? Is `OR` too expensive compared to `AND`? I have lots of queries that query documents by list of `id`s. Currently, I can make one simple query using `OR` with these `id`s to get all necessary documents at one round trip to the database. Sounds like I'd have to make `n` query calls to get `n` documents for Firestore and wonder if that is going to cause any performance problems since the slowest query will determine how long it's going to take to get `n` documents.