# collection where with Array with many values

Tags: firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

Firestore collection for office doc like this

```
{
 officeId: 'OF005'
 userIds:[
   "U001",
   "U002",
   "U003",
   "U004",
   "U005"
 ]
},
{
 officeId: 'OF005'
 userIds:[
   "U006",
   "U007",
   "U008",
   "U009",
 ]
}
```

In react native app, I connect firestore like this

```
    firestoreConnect(props => [
    { collection: 'office',
      where: ['userIds', '==', props.id],
    },
  ]),
```

and prop.id is the id of user I want to get all offices he works

or I want to search by office id some thing like this

```
firestoreConnect(props => [
    { collection: 'office',
      where: ['officeId', '==', ["OF001", "OF003", "OF004"]],
    },
  ]),
```

can i do this.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46721517/google-firestore-how-to-get-document-by-multiple-ids-in-one-round-trip and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46726673/firebase-firestore-or-query and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46805749/firebase-firestore-or-query-alternative and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46719441/google-firestore-what-is-or-equivalent and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48028440/how-to-accomplish-where-in-query-in-cloud-firestore

Answer (score 1):

You will need to use a Map of Values.  Take a look at 
[Working with Arrays, Lists, and Sets](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/arrays)